# How to pass arguments to Grails in command line?

Tags: grails

I'm trying (Grails 1.3.7):

```
grails tomcat deploy -Dtomcat.deploy.username=abc
```

With no effect. Is it a correct syntax? I can't find it in documentation...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving the `-Dtomcat.deploy.username=abc` to be right after `grails` in the command? i.e.:

```
grails -Dtomcat.deploy.username=abc tomcat deploy
```

Two reasons why I suggest this:

- In the past, I know I've had trouble declaring `-D` properties at the end of the command (like you're observing).
- I know that `grails -Dserver.port=xxxx run-app` *does* work, since I use it often, and that's using the `-D` before any other arguments to `grails`.